# ElasticSearch aggregation results do not match each other

Tags: elasticsearch

I was working on a sample data set which consist of e-commerce transactions to learn Elastic Search.

When I query for transaction count per price interval of 10 I found that there are 514354 records found whose UnitPrice field is in between 0 - 10:

[image]

However when I query for number of the transactions whose UnitPrice is less than or equal to 10 and greather than or equal to 0, i found that there are 514373 records:

[image]

Why don't these records match each other?

Comment: Could it be because of the `lte` clause ? have you tried `lt` ?

Comment: Thanks Paulo, that was the reason.